# Function that calculate distance for data with both binary and numeric columns?

Tags: r

Is there a distance function that can calculate both binary and numeric column distances at once?

```
tibble( Observation = c(1:6), V1 = c(3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 5),
    V2 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "a"), 
    label = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Blue")) %>% 
select(2:4) %>% 
fastDummies::dummy_cols() %>% 
select(c(-V2, -label))
```

I typically use dist(df, method = 'binary'), but now I have a numeric column with the new dummy columns I created. The numeric column, V1, is equally important as the dummy variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `distmix` function from `kmed` where we specify the index of numeric/binary/categorical columns in `idnum/idbin/idcat` respectively.  It is mentioned in the `?distmix`

> idnum -
> A vector of column index of the numerical variables.

> idbin  -
> A vector of column index of the binary variables.

> idcat -
> A vector of column index of the categorical variables.

```
library(kmed)
distmix(df1, idnum = 1, idbin = 2:ncol(df1))
```

In the example data, numeric column is the first column and all other columns are binary, thus we specify `2:ncol(df1)` as index for `idbin`

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble( Observation = c(1:6), V1 = c(3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 5),
    V2 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "a"), 
    label = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Blue")) %>% 
select(2:4) %>% 
fastDummies::dummy_cols() %>% 
select(c(-V2, -label))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the arguments idnum = 1, idbin = 2:ncol()?